# If not (a and not b) and if (not a and b)

Tags: logic

Can anyone explain why these two statements aren't equal?

```
if not(a and not b): 
// do some stuff


if (not a and b):
// do some stuff
```

I tried to make my program more understandable by changing the first statement to the second but it doesn't work. I don't totally understand why.

Comment: Two things: 1) Make sure the precedence of the different logical operators are what you think they are (including left vs right associative) 2) If you're ever REALLY confused, make a truth table (result for all possible inputs). Verify and compare.

Comment: You forgot to negate completely, it's easier if you write a program to iterate through the truth tables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look into De Morgan's Thereom, half of which is <sup>(a)</sup>:

```
not(p and q) -> not(p) or not(q)
```

In terms of how that applies to your situation, just replace `p` with `a` and `q` with `not(b)`:

```
not(a and not b) -> not(a) or not(not(b))
                 -> not(a) or b
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The other half is:

```
not(p or q) -> not(p) and not(q)
```

Answer (score 1):

`if not(a and not b)` is the same as `if (not a) or b`, not what you wrote.

Comment: How did you get that? Is there a rule for re-writing?

Comment: @9-bits - yes the rule is De Morgan's law - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Answer (score 1):

You also need to flip the 'and' to 'or' due to [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
if not(a and not b)
```

becomes

```
if (not a or b)
```

Comment: you can add to your answer `due to de morgan's law`